# CSS not showing up in root directory

Tags: php, html, css

The CSS for my index page located in the root directory isn't working.  I am using php to include a header that contains a navigation bar, but the css for the navigation bar isn't working.  It works on other pages fine, but any page located in the root index doesn't have the css.

Edit: Solved by changing the path to the url and then the file directory of the css.

```
Solved
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrapwebsite/CSS/main.css">

Index.php
    <html>
    <?php    
        include '/includes/header.php';
    ?>
    </html>

header.php
    <html>
    <title>Bootstrap Basics</title>

    <!-- Gather all Required CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"      href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- End the css get -->

    <!-- Gather the jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End the jquery get -->

    <div>
        <header id="navigationHeader" class="navbar" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left mainnav-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a id="logo" href="#"><img src=""></img></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li>
                        <h4><i class="fa fa-group"></i><a href="http://localhost/bootstrapwebsite/players/players.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;Players&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></h4>
                      </li>      

                      <li>
                        <h4><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="http://localhost/bootstrapwebsite/shop/shop.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;Shop&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></h4>
                      </li>

                      <li>
                        <h4><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i><a href="http://localhost/bootstrapwebsite/leaderboards/leaderboards.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;Leaderboards&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></h4>
                      </li>

                      <li>
                        <h4><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="http://localhost/bootstrapwebsite/support/support.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;Support&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></h4>
                      </li> 

                      <li>
                        <h4>
                            <a href="http://localhost/bootstrapwebsite/Registration/login.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Guest&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        </h4>
                      </li>          
                    </ul>
                </nav> 
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </header>
    </div>
</html>

<!-- javascript to determine current page and set it as active -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {    
    //Get CurrentUrl variable by combining origin with pathname, this ensures that any url appendings (e.g. ?RecordId=100) are removed from the URL
    var CurrentUrl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
    //Check which menu item is 'active' and adjust apply 'active' class so the item gets highlighted in the menu
    //Loop over each <a> element of the NavMenu container
    $('#navbar a').each(function(Key,Value)
        {
            //Check if the current url
            if(Value['href'] === CurrentUrl)
            {
                //We have a match, add the 'active' class to the parent item (li element).
                $(Value).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
 });
</script>
<!-- end javascript -->
```

[image: The result of the page]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/header.css">
```

If the PHP file is in the root directory, It can´t access to ".." because It doesn´t exist. Just change the href from "../CSS/main.css" to "CSS/main.css" and It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in ROOT directory than this must be the case that your CSS files are inside the folder called "CSS" which lies in ROOT directory so modify your code as:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="CSS/main.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/header.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the base tag might help here.

```
<head>
    <base href="websiterootdirectorypath/or/baseurl/" />
</head>
```

This should go within the head before any of your css or script links. Then in the paths for your css or scripts you just reference their paths going in from the root. So

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/header.css">
```

And the paths won't break for the pages no matter where they sit within your site structure.